# How to show the border of every movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been looking for hours to find out how you display a border around every MovieClip in Flash. I've done it once but I can't seem to find it at all. What happens is that a blue (I think) box is drawn for the bounding box of the movieclip, and it does this for every movieclip automatically, so I don't think it's creating a border manually for every movieclip you add.

In addition this box doesn't rotate with the movieclip, instead it is just a square that completely surrounds the movieclip. If the movieclip rotates, the square just gets bigger or smaller to match.

Thanks in advance if you can help!!

Comment: The closest thing that comes to my mind is "show redraw regions" in the debugger player. That draws RED lines around everything that changes. Not quite what you mean I'm afraid...

Comment: Wait, that actually might be it.. 

Yup! I think that's what I'm looking for. Not sure how I got blue mixed up with red, but doesn't matter! Thank you! Please put it as an answer so I can label it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for showing the redraw regions. When viewing your swf with the debug player you have extra options when you right click on the Flash content. Clicking on "Show redraw regions" will show red rectangles around regions that are redrawn.

Showing a border around all display objects all the time is not something that can be achieved automatically.